# Sql Query is throwing an ODBCException:

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

Following Sql Query is throwing an ODBCException:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "Select Max(" + primaryKey + ") from " + tableName + " where " + primary_key + " >= " + strt_rng[ftr_index] + " and " + primary_key + " < " + end_rng;
```

Actual Query is as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(FtreId) FROM tbmftre WHERE FtreId >=101 AND FtreId < 1000
```

Am i missing quotes in above query?

Comment: What is the type of `strt_rng`?

Comment: type of strt_rng is string array

Comment: And what is the exception exactly? Also, the quotes around 101 and 1000 are part of the string is it? I can't find them in your query.

Comment: Check the string in debug mode ,Match the string with the tested query. You can use create query if the connection is made in server explorer.Using Odbcparameter will be a good practice

Comment: I tried both: with quotes and without quotes around 101 and 1000 then also Exception thrown is:ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.15]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>= '101' and  < '1001'' at line 1

Comment: shree sir, is there any mistake in the query?

Comment: sorry sir, I made the mistake while writing the primary_key instead of primaryKey. sorry but thank you for your valuable time